# How to generate a list of string + yearly increments?

Tags: python

I have a string "sales". How do I generate the list -
`['sales_2005', 'sales_2006', 'sales_2007'.......'sales_2014']`

I have tried `for i in str(range(2005,2014)): print('sales_' + i)`

This does not work.

Comment: You've tagged it Pandas, but what does Pandas have to do with this list? Do you really want it as a series? Also, printing won't help you get a list--you need something like `[f"sales_{x}" for x in range(2005, 2015)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do:

```
[f"sales_{year}" for year in range(2004, 2017)]
```

Output is:

```
['sales_2004',
 'sales_2005',
 'sales_2006',
 'sales_2007',
 'sales_2008',
 'sales_2009',
 'sales_2010',
 'sales_2011',
 'sales_2012',
 'sales_2013',
 'sales_2014',
 'sales_2015',
 'sales_2016']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only years 2005 - 2014, then you can do range(2005,2014)

```py
sales_list = []
for n in range(2005, 2014)
    sales_list.append('sales_'+n)
```